# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make the bot send a random group of text from a subreddit?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to send a random joke from r/jokes. I already have it able to send a meme from r/memes:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(".meme"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xFF5733)

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await message.channel.send(embed = em)
```

How would I modify this to send a joke?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the code needed to make that change, only need to select text instead of an image.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(".meme"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xFF5733)

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await message.channel.send(embed = em)
  if message.content.startswith(".joke"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("jokes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    text = random_sub.selftext
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xFF5733, description = text)

    await message.channel.send(embed = em)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a bunch! (I'm pretty new to programming)